# Icon Composer in Xcode from App Store

Tags: xcode, icons, xcode4.5

I downloaded xcode (4.5) from the appstore and am trying to find icon composer.  When I've looked through all the subdirs in /Applications/Xcode and can't find a thing.  I've looked in:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/
```

and all I see is:

```
Accessibility Inspector.app 
FileMerge.app
Printer Simulator.app
Application Loader.app
Instruments.app
iPhone Simulator.app
```

I've gone to xcode->open developer tools in the gui and see nothing.  I even built the locate db on my machine and tried searching for it...nothing.  Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Icon Composer was deprecated because it was unable to deal with 1024x1024 icons needed for Mac Retina resolution.
Instead they recommend using icon sets in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH7-SW2).

Comment: Just went ahead and did exactly as the documentation says.  Worked perfectly and was very easy.  Thanks for your help. @massimobio

Answer (score 2):

"Icon Composer" is in the "Graphics Tools" which can be downloaded separately from the ADC-Website (as all other "Tools" like "Hardware IO Tools", "Dashcode", "Audio Tools" and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Per @massimobio's advice I think I'll follow the new recommendations.

Comment: me too :) anyway, I like the Icon Composer because it allows me to preview the icon in the Dock, so it's kinda useful for media-developement.